# Как работают представленные операторы на Java?

Tags: java

Имеется следующий код:

```
public static int gcd_2(int a, int b) 
{
    int t;
    while (b != 0) 
    {
        t = b;         // 6
        b = a % b;     // 7
        a = t;         // 8
    }
    return a;
}
```

Поясните, как работают строки 6-8 (тело цикла `while`), что делают представленные операторы?

Comment: напишите номера строк, непонятно где строки 4-6

Comment: автор про тело цикла

Comment: Это поиск НОД, алгоритм Евклида. Кстати, содержит ошибку - следует убедиться, что оба аргумента положительны, причём второй меньше первого.

Comment: Да, я про тело цикла и вообще весь процесс вычисления НОДа. Получается, что сначала в t мы сохраняем изначальный b, потом в b сохраняем остаток от деления a на b, потом в а сохраняем t, то есть изначальный b. Как мы на НОД выходим, который сохраняется в а?

Comment: @Арман. Вы циклом проходитесь, пока b != 0. Посмотрите, что выводит каждый оператор в каждой итерации. И все поймете

Comment: @Akina, _"причём второй меньше первого"_ - это не надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вам будет понятнее данным методом. Если a или b равен 0, то выводит сумму. Иначе вызывает саму себя с обновленными данными.

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  if(a == 0 || b == 0) return a + b;
  return gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

P.S. Разъясняю для автора. Допустим `a=36`, `b=24`. Тогда при вызове `gcd(36,24)` результат будет 12. Смотрим что произошло.

**Итерация №1**. Ни а, ни b не равно 0, т.е. первое условие игнорируется. Т.к. `b=24`, а остаток от деления `a%b` равно 12, то запускаем саму себя `gcd(24, 12)`.

**Итерация №2**. Ни а, ни b не равно 0. `b=12`, `a%b` равно 0. Идем дальше `gcd(12, 0)`

**Итерация №3**. Т.к. `b=0`, функция возвращает результат суммы a и b. Т.е. 12 + 0 = 12

**Результат**: 12

Comment: `"Чтобы понять рекурсию, нужно понять рекурсию" (с)` :)

Comment: @gil9red. В данном коде, я бы разобрался быстрее. Чем в коде автора.

Comment: @zakiroof, ну это не совсем код автора, это первая ссылка в гуле "как найти нод java", там дано 5 решений)

Comment: Эти все алгориты есть по одной и той же ссылке и они все выдают один и тот же результат, но когда я пытаюсь расписать на бумаге, чтобы хоть как-то понять, ну вообще ничего не сходится у меня:)

Comment: @Арман дополнил свой ответ

Comment: С работой остальных вариантов тоже  разобрался. Всем спасибо!:)

Answer (score 0):

В интернете есть объяснение этого алгоритма, но могу объяснить.

Даны два числа: `a` и `b`. Нам нужно найти наибольший общий делитель.

Допустим, что `a` больше `b`. Произведём целочисленное деление `a` на `b`, получим число, меньшее или равное `a`, которое делится на `b` без остатка, значит, каким бы ни был НОД, всё, что нам нужно - это чтобы он делил без остатка `b` и остаток от деления `a` на `b`. Соответственно, мы можем запустить наш алгоритм заново для `b` и остатка от деления `a` на `b`.
Если остаток от деления `a` на `b` равен нулю, значит `b` - и есть НОД.

Если же `a` меньше, чем `b`, то на следующей итерации они поменяются местами, так как в новой итерации `a` будет равно `b`, а `b` будет равно остатку от деления старых `a`, на `b`, равно `a`, так как остаток от деления меньшего числа на большее равен меньшему числу.

Это просто понять, если представить числа в виде отрезков.